# Existence of a unique polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $z_1, .....z_{m+1}$ are distinct elements of $F$ and $w_1,....,w_{m+1} \in F$. Prove that there exists a unique polynomial $p \in P_m(F)$ such that $p(z_j) = w_j$ for j=1,...m+1.

Any ideas on where to start/go with this one. I'm having quite some trouble with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $P(x)$ = $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} l_{i}(x)w_{i}$ where $l_{i}(x) =  \prod\limits_{j=1, j\neq i}^{n+1} (x-z_{j})/(z_{i}-z_{j})$. Then $P(z_i)=w_i$. To show uniqueness consider any other polynomial $Q(x)$ with similar properties and consider $P(x)-Q(x)$ which will be a polynomial of degree $\leq n$. Show that it has more than $n$ roots thus arriving at a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

You might look up [Lagrange polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Answer (score 2):

Apply the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to the system $\ p(z)\equiv w_j \pmod{ z-z_j}$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally, as above, Lagrange interpolation is a special case of the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT), a useful fact that deserves to be much better known.